# Microsoft SQL Server - Percentages of orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm training on Northwind sample database and got task to do:
"Create query that returns: `CompanyName`, `OrderID`, `SaleAmount` (Value of that Order), Percentage value of that order, Total Value of Customers Orders.

I did it, everything works fine but now i want to add something else: 
**I want to add field that will show percentage share of individual order comaring it to total value of all orders - Sum(SaleAmount)**

I did something like this:

```
SELECT
  CompanyName,
  OrderID,
  SaleAmount,
  CAST(100 * SaleAmount / SUM(SaleAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName) AS decimal(5, 2)) AS 'Percent',
  SUM(SaleAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName) AS Total,
  (SELECT
    SUM(SaleAmount) AS Całość_Zamówienia
  FROM dbo.[Sales Totals by Amount])
  AS Suma_całkowita,
  CAST(100 * SaleAmount / SUM(SaleAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName) AS decimal(11, 2)) AS 'TEST'
FROM dbo.[Sales Totals by Amount]
GROUP BY CompanyName,
         OrderID,
         SaleAmount
```

But it shows stupid things, can you help me please? : )

Comment: What is the current output and what did you expect?

Comment: I would like to get percentage share of individual order, for example Order np. 10524, Sale Amount 3192,65, Total Amount of all orders 291026,66. SaleAmount/ TotalAmount * 100%

Comment: `SUM(SaleAmount) OVER ()` returns the same as your `Suma_całkowita`

Comment: still can't make it : (

Comment: Should be similar to your existing `Percent`calculation: `CAST(100 * SaleAmount / SUM(SaleAmount) OVER() as decimal(5,2))`

Comment: Ok i get it! Thank you dnoeth! Now i realised that i need to type "OVER ()"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT CompanyName, OrderID, SaleAmount,
        CAST(100 * SaleAmount / SUM(SaleAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyName) as decimal(5,2)) as 'Percent',
        SUM(SaleAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyName) as Total,
        (SELECT Sum(SaleAmount) as Całość_Zamówienia FROM dbo.[Sales Totals by Amount]) as Suma_całkowita
        ,CAST(100 * SUM(SaleAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyName)/ (select sum(SaleAmount) from dbo.[Sales Totals by Amount])  as decimal(11,2)) as 'TEST'
        FROM dbo.[Sales Totals by Amount] 
        GROUP BY CompanyName, OrderID, SaleAmount
```